# ruby 'html_safe' in select_tag what is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a novice ruby developer.

```
<%= select_tag "access", "<option>Read</option><option>Write</option>".html_safe, multiple: true, class: 'form_input'%>
```

'html_safe' <<< what is used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`html_safe`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) is here to actually use the HTML tags inside the string as actual HTML.

For example:

- `"<p>Hello</p>".html_safe` will actually print a HTML tag `p` wrapping the string `"Hello"`
- `"<p>Hello</p>"` will output `"<p>Hello</p>"` inside the page (`<p>` tags not being evaluated as HTML)

---

**In your case**, `"<option>Read</option><option>Write</option>".html_safe` will output two option HTML tags with "Read" and "Write".

---

**A better way** to generate options for a select is ... [`options_for_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select):

```
select_tag 'access', options_for_select(['Read', 'Write'])
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in unsafe mode, the default, then all HTML-specific characters are escaped to their entity equivalent. That is `<p>` becomes `&lt;p&gt;`.

Comment: wow...thank you so much!!@MrYoushiji Was understood thanks!!